# How to compare between excel and word/pdf?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have excel file that I want to compare it with a bunch of pdf/word files,
for example the excel got those cells:

```
a   100
b   200
c   300
```

and in the pdf/word there is also table that look almost the same:

```
a   105
b   200
c   300
```

I want a way to check every cell in each pdf if it match the cell in the excel
so in this example it will show that row a is not equal 100 - 105.

How can I approach this kind of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to copy the word/pdf data into an Excel worksheet and give it exactly the same form as the data in your Excel file. Then, use standard Excel formulas to compare the data...